# problem to replacing in some values of columns from one data frame to another data frame in R

Tags: r, replace, reshape

I have df1 as below that some values of columns between 'Du' and 'D_R' are 'NA'.

```
id   Date       Du  dm  htn hf  D_R W_B
1   99/07/19    1   0   0   0   0   6.2
1   99/07/23    1   0   0   0   0   7
2   99/10/30    6   NA  1   NA  NA  6.2
2   99/11/01    6   NA  1   NA  NA  5.2
2   99/11/02    6   NA  1   NA  NA  7.1
3   99/11/03    6   NA  NA  1   NA  9.4
3   99/11/04    6   NA  NA  1   NA  11.5
3   99/11/05    6   NA  NA  1   NA  14.7
4   99/08/19    5   0   0   0   0   3.3
5   99/06/19    6   0   0   0   0   11
6   99/06/20    NA  1   NA  0   0   6.1
6   99/06/21    NA  1   NA  0   0   3.8
7   99/06/22    4   1   11  0   0   3.8
8   99/06/23    2   1   4   0   0   2
8   99/06/24    2   1   4   0   0   4
9   99/06/25    5   4   7   NA  0   NA
```

The df2 is for some id has complete values relate to columns between 'Du' and 'D_R':

```
id  Du  dm  htn hf  D_R
1   1   0   0   0   0
2   6   2   1   2   5
3   6   5   1   4   7
4   5   0   0   0   0
5   6   0   0   0   0
6   5   1   5   0   0
7   4   1   11  0   0
8   2   1   4   0   0
```

Now, I want to replace some values in df2 instead in NA at df1. My target data frame is:

```
id  Date       Du   dm  htn hf  D_R W_B
1   99/07/19    1   0   0   0   0   6.2
1   99/07/23    1   0   0   0   0   7
2   99/10/30    6   2   1   2   5   6.2
2   99/11/01    6   2   1   2   5   6.2
2   99/11/02    6   2   1   2   5   6.2
3   99/11/03    6   5   1   4   7   5.2
3   99/11/04    6   5   1   4   7   5.2
3   99/11/05    6   5   1   4   7   5.2
4   99/08/19    5   0   0   0   0   3.3
5   99/06/19    6   0   0   0   0   11
6   99/06/20    5   1   5   0   0   6.1
6   99/06/21    5   1   5   0   0   3.8
7   99/06/22    4   1   11  0   0   3.8
8   99/06/23    2   1   4   0   0   2
8   99/06/24    2   1   4   0   0   4
9   99/06/25    5   4   7   NA  0   NA
```

I appreciate it if anybody shares his/her code for replacing values between 'Du' and 'D_R' with missing values in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be done by doing a join with `id` and then `fcoalesce` the `intersect`ing columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), "id")
setDT(df1)[df2,  (nm1) := Map(fcoalesce, .SD, mget(paste0('i.', nm1))), 
   on = .(id), .SDcols = nm1]
```

-output

```
> df1
       id     Date    Du    dm   htn    hf   D_R   W_B
    <int>   <char> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <num>
 1:     1 99/07/19     1     0     0     0     0   6.2
 2:     1 99/07/23     1     0     0     0     0   7.0
 3:     2 99/10/30     6     2     1     2     5   6.2
 4:     2 99/11/01     6     2     1     2     5   5.2
 5:     2 99/11/02     6     2     1     2     5   7.1
 6:     3 99/11/03     6     5     1     1     7   9.4
 7:     3 99/11/04     6     5     1     1     7  11.5
 8:     3 99/11/05     6     5     1     1     7  14.7
 9:     4 99/08/19     5     0     0     0     0   3.3
10:     5 99/06/19     6     0     0     0     0  11.0
11:     6 99/06/20     5     1     5     0     0   6.1
12:     6 99/06/21     5     1     5     0     0   3.8
13:     7 99/06/22     4     1    11     0     0   3.8
14:     8 99/06/23     2     1     4     0     0   2.0
15:     8 99/06/24     2     1     4     0     0   4.0
16:     9 99/06/25     5     4     7    NA     0    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L), Date = c("99/07/19", "99/07/23", "99/10/30", 
"99/11/01", "99/11/02", "99/11/03", "99/11/04", "99/11/05", "99/08/19", 
"99/06/19", "99/06/20", "99/06/21", "99/06/22", "99/06/23", "99/06/24", 
"99/06/25"), Du = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, NA, 
NA, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L), dm = c(0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), htn = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 11L, 4L, 4L, 7L), hf = c(0L, 0L, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), D_R = c(0L, 
0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    W_B = c(6.2, 7, 6.2, 5.2, 7.1, 9.4, 11.5, 14.7, 3.3, 11, 
    6.1, 3.8, 3.8, 2, 4, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:8, Du = c(1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L
), dm = c(0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), htn = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 4L), hf = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    D_R = c(0L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. In my real data, I used your code but I got this error:                         
Error in (function (...)  : 
  Item 2 is type integer but the first item is type double. Please coerce before coalescing.                                                                                                                  
could you please guide me that how can i solve that error?

Comment: @Mohammad just change the type of one of the datasets to match the type in another i.e. `df1$item <- as.numeric(df1$item)` assuming the df2 column type item is numeric